# Apply color based on delay

Tags: jquery

I have a set of li's and i want to set background color for each li after delay in between each li.

ex: if 1 li is colored red, then after some delay(800), the present colored li should be removed and the next li should be colored, should proceed for the rest.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul').each(function(i, j){
    $(this).eq(i).css('background-color', 'red').delay(1000).removeAttr('style');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fpYdt/7/)

Please correct me, where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var $li = $('ul li');

$li.each(function(i, li) {
    var that = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $li.removeAttr('style');

        that.css('background-color', 'red');
    }, i * 800);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ5eh/)**

Comment: hey, this one works good :), but i was just guessing, can it be done using .delay and still optimized code, Can you please show me can it be done with out using setTimeout.

Comment: Yeah sure, one moment. The method I posted above is what first came to mind.

Comment: Edit - it's not possible with `.delay()`. `.delay()` only works for queue based methods such as animations, not `css()` or `removeAttr()`. Besides, there's nothing wrong with using `setTimeout()`, as that's what jQuery uses internally with `delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

- You are iterating over all `ui` elements, when I think you want to iterate over all `li` elements
- Inside the iteration, `$(this)` will refer to the element at the current index, so there is no need to use - or rather, you cannot use - `eq(i)` here. `$(this).css(...)` will suffice.
- `.removeAttr` is not an animation. It doesn't use the effects queue, and as such it cannot be delayed in this manner. Use `setTimeout`.
- Having corrected all the above, you must still note that the iteration will loop through all elements very quickly. The timeout being set should account for this in some manner, eg. `i*1000` *or* your timeout should call itself recursively and advance the loop in that manner, but that would entail a rather complete rewrite.

Example:

```
function highlight(list, index) {
    list.removeAttr('style').eq(index%list.length).css('background-color', 'red');
    setTimeout(highlight, 1000, list, ++index);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kt3jc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/fpYdt/8/:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="red">list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
    <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Added CSS:

```
.red {background-color:red}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function(){
        var red = $('li.red');
        red.removeClass('red');
        var next = red.next();
        if(next.length > 0)            
            red.next().addClass('red');
        else
            $('li').first().addClass('red');
    },3000);
});
```